# How to take extra space and newline separated number input in python 2.7.7?

Tags: list, python-2.7, input

I need these numbers to append to a list.

1427  0

876652098643267843
527653

I have tried:

```
nums = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]
```

But it just gives only first two numbers. 
1427 0

How to get all these numbers in nums?

Comment: How are you getting your newline into `raw_input()`? This function will return when you hit enter.

Comment: Should I try append()? But newline is a problem here.

Comment: @RubelAhmed No, it will lead you to other errors. You should redefine your question.

Comment: As DeepSpace comments, you need to re-define your question. You *cannot* get the input you describe via `raw_input()`, so therefore your second statement makes no sense.

Comment: is there any function or technique to take such inputs? @DeepSpace

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't get a newline by `raw_input`.
2. Why don't you simply ask the user before hand how many numbers they want to input? Note that this example, like yours, is vulnerable to `ValueError` in case the user inputs a value that can't be converted to an `int`.

   ```
   amount = int(raw_input())
   nums = [int(raw_input()) for _ in range(amount)]
   ```

Comment: I don't know the number of inputs. it may be 10^18 or any number.

Comment: @RubelAhmed You don't need to know. You ask the users for this info.

Comment: @ DeepSpace, the inputs will be given by machine. Only the inputs in this way.

Comment: @RubelAhmed Again, like me and SiHa explained: `raw_input` doesn't let you (or a machine) to input a newline character. It will simply end the input with an empty string. You have to rethink the design of your code.

Comment: OK, I realised it will not work in this way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate your `raw_input`s until you get an EOF.

Code could be:

```
try:
    nums = []
    while True:
        line = raw_input()
        nums.extend(line.split())
except EOFError:
    nums
```

Comment: This won't necessarily work, not unless we know what "machine" or method OP uses to get their input from.  Most of the times this will lead to an infinite loop because even pressing the 'enter' key, inputting an empty string or '\n' won't raise `EOFError` or any exception at all.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Depending on the system, you can generate an EOF on interactive input with Ctrl D (Unix, Linux or IDLE any system) of Ctrl-Z (Windows).